# Ubuntu20.04: TouchPad not work in HP laptop

Tags: 20.04, touchpad

I tried some solutions from the internet, but all not work.
`xinput` command

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PixArt USB Optical Mouse                  id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP True Vision FHD Camera: HP T           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID 5 button array                  id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

`uname -a` command:

```
Linux OMEN-HP 5.15.0-97-generic #107~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 9 14:20:11 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

mouse & TouchPad

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQaIH.png)